# What is default Javascript SignalR Client AuthenticationSchemes?

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I have two clients for my SignalR app: Javascript client for web browsers and Android client ([Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client](https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client)) that use JWT Bearer Authentication.

I added this attribute to my SignalR Hub:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MyHub : Hub
```

And my *Startup.cs* file:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        //…
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
                };
            });
        services.AddSignalR();
        //…
```

Android client login successfully with header authentication bearer token. **But** web client comes failed connecting to the hub (401 Unauthorized).

When I remove [Authorize] attribute the javascript client works!

What is default Javascript SignalR Client AuthenticationScheme? Or what is the issue I made?

I use dotnet core 2.1, Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR and my IDE is Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: What's your JavaScript client connection builder look like? Are you passing in the token via the provider or query string?

Answer (score 0):

This is from [SignalR docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bearer-token-authentication):

In standard web APIs, bearer tokens are sent in an HTTP header. However, SignalR is unable to set these headers in browsers when using some transports. When using WebSockets and Server-Sent Events, the token is transmitted as a query string parameter.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // ...
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // ...

            // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
            // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
            // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
            // Server-Sent Events request comes in.

            // Sending the access token in the query string is required due to
            // a limitation in Browser APIs. We restrict it to only calls to the
            // SignalR hub in this code.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/security#access-token-logging
            // for more information about security considerations when using
            // the query string to transmit the access token.
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                    // If the request is for our hub...
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))
                    {
                        // Read the token out of the query string
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```